# print array items 3 per line

Tags: arrays, ruby

With the below my whole dynamic array outputs, 10 per line - I would like to setup a param to have 3 array items per line, after 3 another line is created.

```
...     
     while i < arr.length
          print "Define types of coffee drinks: "
          coffee = gets.chomp
          arr[i] = coffee
          i += 1
        end
        puts arr.join(", ")
      break
...
```

For instance after my dynamic array is created it outputs like:

```
black iced coffee, cold brew, espresso, flat white, frap, latte, drip, fancy, smancy
```

All 10 on one line, I'd like it to output like:

```
black iced coffee, cold brew, espresso,
flat white, frap, latte, 
drip, fancy, smancy
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, because you have not provided a [mcve]. What is `arr`? Your code sample should be **complete** - i.e. I should be able to copy+paste and run it myself.

Comment: The second line in your output (with four elements) is a typo, right? And you should `a.push(coffee)` rather than worry about `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array.each_slice(3).with_index do |part, ind|
  puts part.join(", ") + (ind == 3 ? "" : ",")
end
```

is probably what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution that *almost* gets what you asked for:

```
array.each_slice(3) { |part| puts part.join(', ') }

#=> black iced coffee, cold brew, espresso
    flat white, frap, latte, drip
    fancy, smancy
```

However, this is missing the final comma on the first two lines.

If this is important, you might try to add it like so:

```
array.each_slice(3) { |part| puts part.join(', ') + ',' }

#=> black iced coffee, cold brew, espresso,
    flat white, frap, latte, drip,
    fancy, smancy,
```

...but now it's also on the last line!

There's probably a slightly more elegant way to do this, but it's a bit fiddly... How about:

```
array.each_slice(3).with_index do |part, i|
  puts part.join(", ") + (array.size % 3 == i ? '' : ',')
end

#=> black iced coffee, cold brew, espresso,
    flat white, frap, latte, drip,
    fancy, smancy
```

Comment: Nice on spotting the trailing commas but you could use two `Array#join` calls to avoid messing around with indices like that.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use `each_slice` and `join` to build the individual lines:

```
a.each_slice(3).map { |a| a.join(', ') }
```

and then `join` again to join the lines together:

```
puts a.each_slice(3).map { |a| a.join(', ') }.join(",\n")
```

This assumes, of course, that each line except the last is supposed to contain three elements and that the second line of your sample output is a typo.